# Optimize optional flow Java 8+

Tags: java, spring-boot, java-8

I am trying to optimize below code:-

```
Optional<MyObject> result = fooRepository.findById(Id);
if(result.isPresent()) {
   return result.getSpecificValue();
}else {
   return null;
}
```

I tried to convert this to:-

```
return result.map(MyObject::getSpecificValue).orElse(null);
```

But somehow, after execution it thows NPE saying

*Cannot invoke "java.util.Optional.map(java.util.function.Function)" because "result" is null*

I spent a few hours figuring out to optimize it, I am not sure if I am doing something wrong.
I would be really grateful for any help or any guiding pointers.

Comment: It means your result (ie instanse of Optioanl class) is null. You would better check why your repository return null instead of empty Optional

Comment: There was an issue with findById() method. Its behaviour was wired , it should have returned Optional.empty() but was returning null for some reason. Thank you @yahorbarkouski for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I bet this indicates a problem with the `findById` method in `fooRepository` -  it shouldn't return null, but rather an `Optional.empty()` when no object is found with the given id, so you might need to check how `findById` is implemented.

But if for some specific reason, you don't have control over the `fooRepository` code and it can return null, you may use `Optional.ofNullable()` + `flatMap()` to get the desired result:

```java
Optional<MyObject> result = Optional.ofNullable(fooRepository.findById(Id));
return result.flatMap(MyObject::getSpecificValue).orElse(null);
```

Answer (score 1):

Exception says `fooRepository.findById` returns null instead of empty Optional. It's not supposed, so I would suggest to check why it happens.

Anyway, to deal with `result` equals to `null`, you could use

```
Optional.ofNullable(result).flatMap(Function.identity()).map(MyObject::getSpecificValue).orElse(null);
```

Comment: kindly reminder: you could upvote if was helpful